# What is the meaning of ${}^n C_k \times {}^n P_k$?

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, permutations, combinations

I am trying to understand the [bulls and cows](http://slovesnov.users.sourceforge.net/bullscows/bulls_and_cows.pdf) document, Page $6$, equivalences. 
Can someone please tell me what author means when he says 
$\boldsymbol{ {}^n C_k \times {}^n P_k}$ like ${}^4 P_0 \times {}^4 C_0$ and ${}^4 P_1 \times {}^4 C_1$?

$$\sum_{n=\max(0, p-(d-u))}^{n=p} {}^u P_n \cdot {}^p C_n = \sum \frac{u!}{(u-n)!} \cdot \frac{p!}{(p-n)! \cdot n!}$$

$$\begin{array}{ccrcr}
{}^4 P_0 \cdot {}^4 C_0 &=&  1 \cdot 1 &=&  1 \\
{}^4 P_1 \cdot {}^4 C_1 &=&  4 \cdot 4 &=& 16 \\
{}^4 P_2 \cdot {}^4 C_2 &=& 12 \cdot 6 &=& 72 \\
{}^4 P_3 \cdot {}^4 C_3 &=& 24 \cdot 4 &=& 96 \\
{}^4 P_4 \cdot {}^4 C_4 &=& 24 \cdot 1 &=& 24 \\
\hline
&&&&209
\end{array}$$

Comment: $nCk$ is the k-combinations of n elements. 

$nPk$ is the permutations of n elements taken k at a time

Comment: @Test123 But in the above question What is the meaning of nCk X nPk ? If you can take an example and explain what will be result set ?

Comment: ${_nC_k}$ is the number of ways you can form committees of k people from n people (or choose k items from a group of n).  ${_nP_3}$ is the number of ways you can choose a president, vp, and secretary (or $k$ distinct items) from a group of $n$ people.

Comment: @PaulHurst so if I want to calculate nCk **X** nPk , then for a n = 4 = {0,1,2,3} . The result will be a cartisian product of nCk X nPk = 16 = {0},{1},{2},{3} X {0},{1},{2},{3} . Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: It's not a Cartesian product.  It's just simple multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

$4P2=4\cdot 3=12, 4C2=4\cdot 3/2=6$,so$4P2 \times 4C2=12\times 6=72$

Comment: @PaulHurst - so my understanding is if n = {0,1,2,3} 4 elements
k = 1
nCk = {0},{1},{2},{3} and
nPk = {0},{1},{2},{3}

nCk X nPk = 16 = {0},{1},{2},{3} X {0},{1},{2},{3}

Comment: @Shakti:  that is correct, but it would be better to use $k=2$ so the difference between permutations and combinations shows up.

Comment: $_nC_k = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$,   

 $_nP_k = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!} = n(n-1)\cdots (n-k+1)$